# Create dropdownlist with delete button in this itemrenderer

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I works with Flex 4.5 and I like to create a custom dropdownlist. Indeed, I'd like to show in each line on my dropdownlist a label and a delete button.
The goal is to delete the line on click to delete button.
This look like simple, but I don't found how to do that.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Create an itemRenderer to display the delete button and the label in the drop down.  Then when the button is clicked, bubble an event which you can use to remove the item from the dataProvider.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But can you give me code sample to do that? Thanks

Comment: @www.Flextras.com Doesn't work: DropDownList prevents the click of the Button from firing. MouseDown is not prevented though. But then the List's selectedIndex hasn't been set yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to jump through a few hoops for this one because DropDownList prevents any `MouseEvent.CLICK` from an object inside an ItemRenderer from being fired.

First things first: you will need a custom event for this to work. One that carries your item or at least its index. e.g.:

```
public class ItemEvent extends Event {
    public static const REMOVE:String = "itemRemove";

    public var item:MyClass;

    public function ItemEvent(type:String, item:MyClass, 
                              bubbles:Boolean=false, 
                              cancelable:Boolean=false) {
        super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
        this.item = item;
    }

    override public function clone():Event {
        return new ItemEvent(type, item, bubbles, cancelable);
    }

}
```

Then you create a custom ItemRenderer with a 'delete' Button that will dispatch this event.

```
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private function remove():void {
                owner.dispatchEvent(
                    new ItemEvent(ItemEvent.REMOVE, data as MyClass)
                );
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Label id="labelDisplay" verticalCenter="0" left="10" />

    <s:Button verticalCenter="0" right="10" width="16" height="16"
              mouseDown="remove()" />

</s:ItemRenderer>
```

Important here is that you catch the MOUSE_DOWN event of the Button, since its CLICK event doesn't fire (as mentioned before). The `owner` property of the ItemRenderer refers to the List it is a child of.

Now the last piece of the puzzle. Here's your DropDownList with custom ItemRenderer:

```
<s:DropDownList id="myDropDownList" dataProvider="{dp}"
                itemRenderer="MyItemRenderer" />
```

And here's how you listen for that custom event and remove the selected item:

```
myDropDownList.addEventListener(ItemEvent.REMOVE, removeSelectedItem);

private function removeSelectedItem(event:ItemEvent):void {
    var items:IList = myDropDownList.dataProvider;
    var index:int = items.getItemIndex(event.item);
    items.removeItemAt(index);
}
```

Because we caught the MOUSE_DOWN instead of CLICK the `myDropDownList.selectedIndex` property will still be at the previously selected item (or -1 if none was selected). This is why we needed the custom event, because there was no other way of knowing which is the item you want to remove.