# ComboBox auto close

Tags: apache-flex

I'm using a combobox with a custom item renderer, each item containing a "delete" button to remove the corresponding item from the list. The problem is that when I click on this button, the combobox popup automatically closes, how can I force it to stay open when I click on the button ?

This is how is declared my ComboBox :

```
<s:ComboBox id="addressIn" width="150" height="23" skinClass="maincomponents.ServerAddressComboBoxSkin" dataProvider="{this._servers}" enabled="true" enabled.loading="false" />
```

The corresponding skin :

```
<s:SparkSkin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
        xmlns:fb="http://ns.adobe.com/flashbuilder/2009" alpha.disabled=".5"> 

    <!-- host component -->
    <fx:Metadata>
        <![CDATA[ 
        /** 
        * @copy spark.skins.spark.ApplicationSkin#hostComponent
        */
        [HostComponent("spark.components.ComboBox")]
        ]]>
    </fx:Metadata> 

    <!--
        NOTE: this skin file contains sub-parts that may continue to react to
        Style code.  To remove this behavior create new copies of those skins
        and remove the styles.
    -->
    <s:states>
        <s:State name="normal" />
        <s:State name="open" />
        <s:State name="disabled" />
    </s:states>

    <!--- 
        The PopUpAnchor control that opens the drop-down list. 

        <p>In a custom skin class that uses transitions, set the 
        <code>itemDestructionPolicy</code> property to <code>none</code>.</p>
    -->
    <s:PopUpAnchor id="popUp"  displayPopUp.normal="false" displayPopUp.open="true" includeIn="open"
                   left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" itemDestructionPolicy="auto"
                   popUpPosition="below" popUpWidthMatchesAnchorWidth="true">

        <!--- 
            This includes borders, background colors, scrollers, and filters. 
            @copy spark.components.supportClasses.DropDownListBase#dropDown
        -->
        <s:Group id="dropDown">

            <!-- drop shadow -->
            <!--- @private -->
            <s:RectangularDropShadow id="dropShadow" blurX="20" blurY="20" alpha="0.45" distance="7" 
                                     angle="90" color="#000000" left="0" top="0" right="0" bottom="0"/>

            <!-- border -->
            <!--- @private -->
            <s:Rect id="border" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
                <s:stroke>
                    <!--- @private -->
                    <s:SolidColorStroke id="borderStroke" weight="1"/>
                </s:stroke>
            </s:Rect>

            <!-- fill -->
            <!--- Defines the appearance of drop-down list's background fill. -->
            <s:Rect id="background" left="1" right="1" top="1" bottom="1" >
                <s:fill>
                    <!---  
                        @private
                        The color of the drop down's background fill.
                        The default color is 0xFFFFFF.
                    -->
                    <s:SolidColor id="bgFill" color="0xFFFFFF" />
                </s:fill>
            </s:Rect>

            <!--- @private -->
            <s:Scroller id="scroller" left="0" top="0" right="0" bottom="0" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" skinClass="fbcomponents.skinScrollSettingsDD">
                <!--- @copy spark.components.SkinnableDataContainer#dataGroup-->
                <s:DataGroup id="dataGroup" clipAndEnableScrolling="true" itemRenderer="maincomponents.DataList_ServerRepeatedItem">
                    <s:layout>
                        <s:VerticalLayout gap="0" horizontalAlign="contentJustify" requestedMinRowCount="1" requestedMaxRowCount="6"/>
                    </s:layout>
                </s:DataGroup> 
            </s:Scroller>

        </s:Group>
    </s:PopUpAnchor>

    <!---  The default skin is ComboBoxButtonSkin. 
            @copy spark.components.supportClasses.DropDownListBase#openButton
            @see spark.skins.spark.ComboBoxButtonSkin -->
    <s:Button id="openButton" width="20" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" focusEnabled="false"
              skinClass="maincomponents.ServerAddressComboBoxButtonSkin" tabEnabled="false" />  
    <!--- @copy spark.components.ComboBox#textInput -->
    <s:TextInput id="textInput" enabled.disabled="false"
                 left="0" right="19" top="0" bottom="0" 
                 skinClass="maincomponents.ServerAddressComboBoxTextInputSkin"/> 

</s:SparkSkin>
```

And the item renderer :

```
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                xmlns:fc="http://ns.adobe.com/flashcatalyst/2009"
                xmlns:ai="http://ns.adobe.com/ai/2009"
                xmlns:d="http://ns.adobe.com/fxg/2008/dt" dataChange="onDataChangeHandler(event)" valueCommit="adaptBg()"
                xmlns:flm="http://ns.adobe.com/flame/2008"
                minWidth="161" height="20" autoDrawBackground="false" fc:resizable="true">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import mx.events.StateChangeEvent;

            import spark.components.List;

            protected function onDataChangeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                this.title.text = this.data as String;
                this.adaptBg();
            }

             protected function adaptBg():void
            {
                this.bg.color = (itemIndex % 2 == 0) ? 0xEFEFEF : 0xE0E0E0;
            } 

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>


    <s:states>
        <s:State name="normal"/>
        <s:State name="hovered"/>
        <s:State name="selected"/>
    </s:states>
    <s:Rect x="0" y="0" width="161" height="20">
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor id="bg" color="#EFEFEF"/>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>
    <s:Rect x="0" y="0" width="161" height="20"
            visible.normal="false">
        <s:fill>
            <s:LinearGradient x="137" y="0" scaleX="31" rotation="90">
                <s:GradientEntry ratio="0" color="#FFEDD1"/>
                <s:GradientEntry ratio="0.5" color="#FFD180"/>
                <s:GradientEntry ratio="0.51" color="#EBAA1D"/>
                <s:GradientEntry ratio="1" color="#CF951A"/>
            </s:LinearGradient>
        </s:fill>
        <s:fill.hovered>
            <s:SolidColor alpha="0.24" color="#000000"/>
        </s:fill.hovered>
    </s:Rect>
    <s:Button x="5" y="2" width="20" height="16" buttonDown="trace('ok');" />
    <s:RichText id="title" d:id="103" d:userLabel="caldera0003" x="32" verticalCenter="1" ai:aa="2" color="#292929"
                columnCount="1" fontFamily="HelveticaNeueLT Pro 57 Cn" fontSize="14"
                kerning="on" tabStops="S36" flm:variant="34"
                whiteSpaceCollapse="preserve"/>
    <s:Rect width="274" height="31"
            visible="false" alpha.hovered="0.3"
            alpha.normal="0"
            alpha.selected="0.5">
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor color="0xCED7EE"/>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>
</s:ItemRenderer>
```

Comment: You're probably going to have to extend the ComboBox and prevent the default behavior of closing the drop down list on mouse click. Spark ComboBox extends DropDownListBase, which has a protected method named `item_mouseDownHandler()` that you might be able to override to do this.

Comment: I have answered this one before. Let me look that up for you.

Comment: Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925474/create-dropdownlist-with-delete-button-in-this-itemrenderer/8928105#8928105. That question was about a DropDownList, but the technique should work for ComboBox too.

Comment: @SunilD.: Spark ComboBox does not inherits from DropDownListBase but from ComboBase, and the method `item_mouseDownHandler()` does not seem to exist...

Comment: @RIAStar: thanks for your help, but actually my problem is not how to delete the item, but rather how to keep the popup open when I click on   the 'delete' button.

Comment: Glad the answer was so simple. Just for edification, the Spark `ComboBox` does extend `DropDownListBase`.  It is the MX `ComboBox` class that extends the older `ComboBase`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've mentioned it in the comments, but you pointed out there is a difference with your situation. First read my answer to this question about adding a 'delete' button to DropDownList items: [Create dropdownlist with delete button in this itemrenderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925474/create-dropdownlist-with-delete-button-in-this-itemrenderer/8928105#8928105)

There is only one thing you need to change from that code to get what you want, i.e. the popup must stay open when an item is removed. Go to the custom ItemRenderer, find the 'delete' Button tag and just prevent the event from propagating. If the event doesn't propagate, the DropDownList will never catch it and the popup will never close when the user clicks on the Button.

```
<s:Button verticalCenter="0" right="10" width="16" height="16"
          mouseDown="event.stopImmediatePropagation(); remove()" />
```

Comment: Perfect! `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` is what I was missing, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm understanding something wrong, but can't you just add mouseDown handler on your delete button and stop event propagation in it? Like

```
<s:Button x="5" y="2"
          width="20" height="16"
          mouseDown="button1_mouseDownHandler(event)" buttonDown="trace('ok');"
          />
```

and

```
protected function button1_mouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.stopPropagation();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should extend your combobox to stay open when it loses focus or closes? Pressing delete button causes focus lost event to your combobox.