# Text Input Remove Button like Tag in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3

In Flex Application how to add Remove tag ?
[image: Romove Tag in Text Area]

Another Ex: StackoverFlow Tags Section.. when type `Fx` then hit `Space` some image will be adding..

Just i want some suggestion....

Comment: Create a list with a horizontallayout and custom itemrenderer. What have you tried? We're not here to do your job for you, you know.

Comment: i'm just asking how to do it? i just want some idea about this.... if we know the Terminology about our requirement then easily Search on google and get some idea and then implements our requirements.

Comment: My apologies. I've seen so many poorly asked questions lately and you just took the blame for all of them :( Nevertheless, there's little more I can tell then what I already did: create a List with a custom ItemRenderer (somewhat like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925474/create-dropdownlist-with-delete-button-in-this-itemrenderer/8928105#8928105)

Answer (score 0):

use a library "flex-autocomplete" which is much useful for tag. you can change a skin of tag because you have full source code of it. you can take a demo of this library from here
http://flex-autocomplete.com/demo/#

you can download Source code of this library from here
http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&loc=en_us&extid=1721530

May this will help you..!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a `dataGroup` for this purpose, add an `itemRenderer` in `dataGroup`.
and as JK Patel said add a `textInput` which have `auto-complete` functionality, add a  `BorderContainer` for border styling around `textInput`. Bind a `list` of `tags` in `datagroup`.

here some help regarding dataGroup.

(http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS64909091-7042-4fb8-A243-8FD4E2990264.html)

search by yourself for more help... 
here an other example.

(http://www.hufkens.net/2009/06/flex-4-datagroup-and-itemrenderers/)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in to this Auto complete component which looks same as what u want. Change the style to facebook in the drop down list

**DEMO**
[Facebook like AutoComplete text input demo](http://sketch-out.com/flexautocomplete/demo/#app=7b9d&b817-selectedIndex=0)

**SOURCE**
[Source](https://github.com/hillelcoren/flex-autocomplete)

**Developer site** [Hillel Coren AutoComplete](http://hillelcoren.com/flex-autocomplete/)